# How to make a code run while a view is open in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am wondering how I could get tasks running, but They will not be doing nothing until I allow by doing some action in another device that is recognized by django, but meanwhile I will need to have these tasks running while I have a view open and the actions of these tasks will make some changes in the view, for example playing a sound, changing css's proprieties.

I have looked for some informations about how I could do that, I found the Celery, but It only sets up tasks to be carried out in a certain time.

If you guys could explain how this can be possible and provide some resources so I can learn I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) as a task queue along with RabbitMQ as the broker, for processing your tasks asynchronously. I think you want to keep in-sync your devices, which can be achieved by handling the event from one of device and process it asynchronously, then push that events trigger to other devices by using [django-socketio](http://django-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and there you can do listen to the events and do manipulations on the top like change CSS proprieties.

Comment: correct me, If I didn't get your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So asynchronously means that I will be able to run tasks whenever I want ?

Comment: As soon as I give the green light, I want the tasks to run with the view open, If this is possible to do with Celery, questions solved, just to make sure.

Comment: yes, you can run the task immediately as you receive the event in asynchronous way, or you can provide countdown/eta for the task execution.

Comment: Ok man, Thank you, I'll try.